# ValueError at /accounts/profile/ The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: python, django

This error occurs when a user is either not a superuser or doesn't have a profile image (submitted via userprofile in admin).

ValueError at /accounts/profile/
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/

Error during template rendering

```
In template /Users/joseph/Documents/django/tutorial/accounts/templates/base.html, error at line 17
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

9     <meta charset="utf-8">
10    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
11  
12  <!-- Navigation bar -->
13  
14    <br>
15    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-green bg-light">
16    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/accounts/home">MySite</a>
17    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
18      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
19    </button>
20        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
21    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
22      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
23        <li class="nav-item">
24          <a class="nav-link"   href="/accounts/explore/">Explore</a>
25        </li>
26        </ul>
27      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, models.CASCADE)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
   city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
   website = models.URLField(blank=True, default='')
   contactNumber = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Why does this happen? It can't actually be base.html(extended)? If there is anything else that needs adding to help solve the problem, please let me know .Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the line (in your template file, e.g. `base.html`) where you're rendering the image and add an if condition. Something like:

```
{% if item.image %}
  <img target="_blank" src="{{ item.image.url }}" />
{% endif %}
```

I think it's self-explanatory, but don't hesitate to ask anything if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a 'null=True' to ImageField(). 
Also, check if the image has been successfully uploaded in the admin. If it has, try reuploading the image and retry.